# mysql grant privileges

Tags: mysql, privileges, sql-grant

Having trouble with a mysql grant statement.

I want a user who has:

1. readonly (select) privileges on tables that begin with either 'abc' or 'xyz'
2. AND has the ability to CREATE tables.

Here is what I currently have.  The `.*` syntax is giving me errors:

```
GRANT CREATE, SELECT 
  ON db1.abc.* , db1.xyz.* 
  TO 'some_user'@'%' 
  IDENTIFIED BY 'some_password';
```

Comment: Formatting your question improves readability, and makes it easier for people to understand what you're asking. Click on the `edit` link once again to see how the changes I've made affect the final look of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dot is a separator in MySQL - so in "db1.abc.*" the "db1" is the db name and "abc" is the table name. The "*" is therefore what - a column? That's the wrong syntax to specify columns.

As you can read about in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html, you can see that you put column names in parens:

```
GRANT SELECT (col1), INSERT (col1,col2) ON mydb.mytbl TO 'someuser'@'somehost';
```

Also, you can't wild-card table names - you'll have to list out all the tables explicitly if you have more than one table with a name that begins with 'abc' or 'xyz'.

Comment: thanks, you answered my question with "you can't wild-card table names - you'll have to list out all the tables explicitly"